# Why the separable equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{-t}{y}$ has no equilibrium solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given a separable equation with initial value$$y^{'} = -\frac{t}{y} \qquad y(0)=1$$.

This is an example from the book however I am not sure why this equation has no equilibrium solution. I do know that an equilibrium solution is a value of $y$ for which $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ and this happens when $t=0$. From what I understood, the only time this equation has equilibrium solution is when $y=1$ but the equation suggests 2 values for $y$ which can't be possible for the given IVP. Is that why it has no equilibrium solution? Please help.

[image]

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314432/what-is-the-meaning-of-equilibrium-solution

Comment: An equilibrium solution is usually constant over some open interval of time. This can not be the case here.

Comment: Geometrically, the point is that an equilibrium solution would correspond to a horizontal line $y=y_0$. But the direction field shown in Figure 1.3.4 in the given picture never permits this to be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equilibrium solution to $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(t,y)$ is $y_0$ such that $f(t,y_0) = 0$ for all $t$.

Over here, $f(t,y)=\frac{-t}{y}$. Do you see a value of $y$ such that $\frac{-t}{y} =0$ for all value of $t$? No you do not, which is what is meant by "no equilibrium point".

The equation variable may be $t$, but the equilibrium solutions are always values of $y$. Hopefully now you won't get confused.

Comment: ohhhhh... I see. Makes sense now.

Comment: @marg_ocruz Happy to know.